# unable to compile tex file without deleting .aux and . bbl files

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I delete the files .aux and .bbl the compilation succeed allowing me to generate a PDF file, but if I want to compile without deleting these files the following error message appears.

```
Command Line:   latex.exe --src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "template.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\thèse\Papers\Approach\nouvelle correction\Fadwa Yahya CA4BPS
```

---

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(template.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.

LaTeX Warning: File `example.eps' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fix-cm.sty"
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
(svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2 
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
(svglov3.clo
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
))
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.s
ty"
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
")
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.s
ty"
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")

("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.c
fg")
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def"
)))
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.s
ty")
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
)
("C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvipsnam.d
ef")) (template.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.122 \@w

? h
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Impossible to debug that with no information. Something has written `\@w` to the aux file which is not a defined command. almost always that should have been `\@writefile` but a previous job got aborted for some reason leaving a corrupt aux file. If deleting _all_ the aux files does not fix the problem, make a small document which demonstrates the problem and add to your question.

Comment: Maybe it is just a sort of [this problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211886). See if it still exists when you compile a document which does not contain `babel` package.

Comment: Thank you for the help; the problem is in the bibtex file. I fixed it :)